# Problem with RegEx

Tags: regex

I have a problem with

```
<tx:itypes\b[^>]*>(.*?)</tx:itypes>
```

It should replace the tag and everything inside. It works fine if it's just one line:

```
   <tx:itypes> some stuff here </tx:itypes>
```

But there's 15-20 lines with other tags inside < tx:itypes > 
How can I change it to remove everything? Thanks.

Comment: Obligatory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Never mind - forgot "Dot Matches Newline" option. Sorry :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Perl-compatible regex, then the simplest route would be to add the `s` flag to your expression.

Otherwise, it's semi-common practice to use the `[\d\D]` to match *any* character regardless of line-ending:

```
<tx:itypes\b[^>]*>([\d\D]*?)</tx:itypes>
```